# How to pass argument in java

Tags: java

Hi i am using this code to run the shell script.the thing is i want to pass argument "trng-java" while i am running program.like this

```
like java Classname trng-java
```

code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "/tmp/test.sh", "trng-java"});

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: You mean accept it as input to your program? It's in the `args` array that's the parameter of main.

Comment: If its a variable use `$trng-java`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line arguments are passed to your application in the String[] parameter args, so you should be able to access the value using `args[0]`.

```java
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "/tmp/test.sh", args[0] });
```

Answer (score 5):

The argument you pass in will be found in the args parameters as String yourParam = args[0]

Answer (score 2):

`Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "/tmp/test.sh", args[0]});`

Of course, you will also need to check that args contains at least one argument

Answer (score 2):

When you pass arguments to a java application, they are accessible through the `args[]` array in main.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html which **I am quoting:**

> **Echoing Command-Line Arguments**
>
> The Echo example displays each of its command-line arguments on a line
>   by itself:
>
> ```
> public class Echo {
>     public static void main (String[] args) {
>         for (String s: args) {
>             System.out.println(s);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The following example shows how a user might run Echo. User input is
>   in italics.
>
> ```
> java Echo Drink Hot Java
> Drink
> Hot
> Java
> ```
>
> **Parsing Numeric Command-Line Arguments**
>
> If an application needs to support a numeric command-line argument, it
>   must convert a String argument that represents a number, such as "34",
>   to a numeric value. Here is a code snippet that converts a
>   command-line argument to an int:
>
> ```
> int firstArg;
> if (args.length > 0) {
>     try {
>         firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
>     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>         System.err.println("Argument" + " must be an integer");
>         System.exit(1);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the argument(s) to your command, like this:

```
rt.exec("/bin/sh /tmp/test.sh trng-java");
```

Answer (score 0):

in `public static void main(String[] args)` the args parameter is the arguement. If you use multiple arguement like

```
java Classname a b c
```

Then in your main method args will be an array containing a,b,c

if this is what you want then `args[0]` is the preferred arguement.